# Filter rows that have the same data in different columns

Tags: sql

I have some data that looks like this:

```
 A | B
97 |556
257|803
803|257
257|323
556|97
```

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to filter the results such that it removes the duplicate rows. For example it only shows the row 257|803 and not 803|257. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM T x
WHERE x.A < x.B
OR NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM T y 
   WHERE y.A = x.B AND y.B = x.A
   );
```

The truth table for this strange condition:

```
 A | B  | (A<B) | (NOT exists) | (A<B OR NOT exists)
---+----+-------+--------------+----------------------
97 |556 | True  | False        |  True
257|803 | True  | False        |  True
803|257 | False | False        |  False
257|323 | True  | True         |  True
556|97  | False | False        |  False
```

Result:

```
  a  |  b  
-----+-----
  97 | 556
 257 | 803
 257 | 323
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This will fail for rows with identical values. The OP doesn't say anything about them nor does the example suggest they can be present, but if I were you, I would stipulate the limitation, just in case. +1 for a solution that works for the question as is, though.

Comment: Ah great, this worked really well. Thanks! Just so you know, I already filtered out rows with identical values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Query` for `MYSQL`

```
select distinct greatest(t1.A, t1.B), least(t1.A, t1.B)
from your_table t1 , your_table t2
where t1.B=t2.A and t1.A=t2.B
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96eba/8)**

**[Refer my Answer. Only the inner Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342712/sql-query-how-to-get-items-from-one-col-paired-with-another-but-not-visa-versa/16343404#16343404)**

**`Edit`**

**SQL SERVER** Version

```
select * from
(select 
case when t1.A>t1.B
then t1.A end as A1, 
case when t1.A>t1.B
then t1.B end as B1
from your_table t1 , your_table t2
where t1.B=t2.A and t1.A=t2.B)t
where t.A1 is not null
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96eba/5)**

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't return the `257|323` row. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLServer2005+ use option with CROSS [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test102 t
  OUTER APPLY (
               SELECT t2.A, t2.B
               FROM dbo.test102 t2
               WHERE t.A = t2.B AND t.B = t2.A                 
               ) o               
WHERE t.A > t.B OR o.A IS NULL
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96fb7/2)

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test102 t LEFT JOIN dbo.test102 t2 ON t.A = t2.B AND t.B = t2.A
WHERE t.A > t.B OR t2.A IS NULL
```

Comment: Same question as to @Luv: why is the `257|323` row omitted from the results?

Comment: I thought OP wants to delete these records, but I was wrong. Thank you for the clarifications Andriy. BTW, answer updated(added row omitted).

Comment: Ah, I see, the question could indeed be read that way, your former suggestion now makes sense to me. I think what confused me was that you were *selecting* rows that the OP intended to *remove*, but anyway, I understand your intention. Interestingly, you've ended up with basically the same suggestion as @wildplasser: an inequality and a (differently implemented) anti-join.

Answer (score -2):

in your query add one more where condition - leftparam<=rightparam.
it will eliminate all duplicate reversed pairs. 80|100 ok, 100|80 removed.

Comment: was not this the intended behavior? removed duplicate reversed pairs ?

Comment: Yes missed that , but suppose there is unique record 123|70 , this will get deleted even though its not duplicate

Comment: i think i mis-understood the problem. i thought your problem was that of reversed duplicate pairs.